# Remove Weka Instances if one or more attributes have certain value

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

I have a dataset with multiple numeric attributes and a nominal class, like

```
@relation Example

@attr_1 numeric
@attr_2 numeric
 ...
@attr_n numeric
@class {yes, no}

@data
2,4,...,10,yes
-1,-1,...,3,yes
2,3,...,-1,no
12,6,...,4,no
```

Usually values are bigger than zero, but it appears that one or more numeric attributes can have a negative value `-1`.

**How can I remove the instances with at least one attribute having a negative value?**

I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136310) but I don't explicitly know in which attribute the negative value appears. So, does someone know another more fitting Filter to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on RemoveWithValues filter, specify the attribute index, and focus on last parameter - splitPoint. If the values are smaller than entered value, they would be removed. So your splitPoint value should be 0. Good luck

Comment: But if I'm geting it right the RemoveWithValues filter only allows to specify ONE attribute index (-C option) but no range for .e.g all attributes. So I have to know which attribute to look for or have to explicitly run through all attributes.

Comment: Sorry I get it little wrong. Your're right this is not what are you looking for.